# How to get inputs message to IoT edge device using node-red module?

Tags: node-red, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I managed to deploy the node-red device and get the message from it via node-red output module using the following [tutorial](https://github.com/iotblackbelt/noderededgemodule).

Now I would like to send from Azure IoT Hub portal to IoT edge device "node-red" module a message, i.e. a certain value that I am going to use in the node-red JS code (the parameter which will decide some logic of node-red module processes).

I tried to fix the routes as follows:

```
"my value" INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/{noderedmodule}/inputs/input1\")
```

I believe the second part should be valid `BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/{noderedmodule}/inputs/input1\")`. I need to find out the `FROM` part. Is there a syntax tutroial for the route creation in the module setting step?

I assume I must have developed a custom module and I found the tutorial by Microsoft a bit less informative. Is there any other method to send the data to node-red module via node-red input module?

PS: Or I could use the environment variables somehow to send as input to my nodered?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [Nodered](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message from the Azure Portal to your node-red module then you have the direct method available to you. Select your Edge device in the portal, click on the module name and then pick Direct method. In there you can put in the method name and the payload (which must be valid JSON). On the node red side, you will need to Module Method node. Set the method to the same value that you use in the method name in the portal. You will receive this information in the payload which you can send to a function node. The function node can act upon it and then must send a message back to the Module Method node that contains at least { "status": 200 } otherwise the portal will think the call failed. At this point, in my function node, I typically set the values into a flow variable and have my worker function node read the value and make any necessary changes to its logic flow.

The rooting you are referring to is only for moving messages between modules and to the IoT hub.